# Tyring to use a pivot in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data:

select MorningOrAfternoon, Emp, Meeting_Date, location_name from mytbl

```
 MorningOrAfternoon Emp         Meeting_Date    location_name
 AM                 Charles J   20171103        Oss Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171104        NYC Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171104        BKLN Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171106        Oss Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171107        TT Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171108        Oss Office
 AM                 Charles J   20171109        WP Office
```

My query:

```
select Emp, 'AM' as Time,  day_1 , day_2, day_3, day_4,day_5 day_6, day_7  
from
(

    select t.Emp, t.Meeting_Date, t.location_name, rn='day_'+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (partition by t.Emp order by t.Meeting_Date)) 
        from  mytbl t join
            (                   
                select Meeting_Date, Emp from mytbl where MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'
                group by Meeting_Date, Emp
                having count(location_name ) < 2
            )a
    on a.Meeting_Date = t.Meeting_Date and a.Emp = t.Emp
    where t.MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'

) as x
pivot (max(location_name) for [rn] in (day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4, day_5, day_6, day_7) ) p
order by Emp
```

produces these Results:

```
Emp     Time    day_1       day_2       day_3       day_4       day_6       day_7
Charles J   AM  Oss Office  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Charles J   AM  NULL        Oss Office  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Charles J   AM  NULL        NULL        TT Office   NULL        NULL        NULL
Charles J   AM  NULL        NULL        NULL        Oss Office  NULL        NULL
Charles J   AM  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        WP Office   NULL
```

I would like to use a pivot to create this output:

```
Emp         Time    day_1       day_2           day_3       day_4       day_5   day_6       day_7
Charles J   AM      Oss Office  Oss OfficeNULL  TT Office   Oss Office  Open    WP Office   Open
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Emp, 'AM' as Time,  day_1 , day_2, day_3, day_4,day_5 day_6, day_7  
from
(

    select t.Emp, t.location_name, rn='day_'+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (partition by t.Emp order by t.Meeting_Date)) 
        from  mytbl t join
            (                   
                select Meeting_Date, Emp from mytbl where MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'
                group by Meeting_Date, Emp
                having count(location_name ) < 2
            )a
    on a.Meeting_Date = t.Meeting_Date and a.Emp = t.Emp
    where t.MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'

) as x
pivot (max(location_name) for [rn] in (day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4, day_5, day_6, day_7) ) p
order by Emp
```

As the `Meeting_Date` is unique for each row, even it is not present in the final `SELECT`, the `PIVOT` is made grouping by it and the `emp` column. So, we just need to remove if from the inner `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to script out Pivots without using Pivot function:

```
select 
Emp
,'AM' as Time
,max(case when rn = 'day_1' then location_name) as day_1Location
,max(case when rn = 'day_2' then location_name) as day_2Location
...
from
(

    select t.Emp, t.Meeting_Date, t.location_name, rn='day_'+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (partition by t.Emp order by t.Meeting_Date)) 
        from  mytbl t join
            (                   
                select Meeting_Date, Emp from mytbl where MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'
                group by Meeting_Date, Emp
                having count(location_name ) < 2
            )a
    on a.Meeting_Date = t.Meeting_Date and a.Emp = t.Emp
    where t.MorningOrAfternoon = 'AM'

) as x
group by Emp
```